# How can I optimize the processing a pandas DataFrame and improve the code's readability?

Tags: python, pandas

The code below handles flags in a pandas DataFrame using some dummy variables. The code seems to be very slow with a data set containing 4000 rows.

- Is there a more efficient way to write the same code?
- How can I replace the `for` loops?
- Is there a way to reduce the amount of `if` statements?
- Is there a way of making the code more readable?

code:

```
import pandas as pd
def dummy():
    df=pd.read_csv('DF.csv',header=0)
    df['North']=0
    df['South']=0
    df['Central']=0
    df['West']=0
    df['East']=0
    df['Remote']=0
    for i in range(len(df['Region'])):
        if df['Region'][i]=='North':
            df['North'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='South':
            df['South'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='East':
            df['East'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='West':
            df['West'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='Central':
            df['Central'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='Remote':
            df['Remote'][i]=1
    df['apartment']=0
    df['house']=0
    df['townhouse']=0
    df['unit']=0
    df['villa']=0
    df['acreage']=0
    df['other']=0
    for i in range(len(df['Type_Property'])):
        if df['Type_Property'][i]=='house':
            df['house'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='apartment' or df['Type_Property'][i]=='flat':
            df['apartment'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='townhouse':
            df['townhouse'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='villa':
            df['villa'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='acreage+semi+rural' or df['Type_Property'][i]=='terrance':
            df['acreage'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='unit':
            df['unit'][i]=1
        else:
            df['other']=1
    df.to_csv('Dummied.csv')

dummy()
```

Comment: If this code is working, you should post it on CodeReview

Comment: To quote [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), SO's scope is limited to questions about *specific problems*. A generalized request for improvements to already-working code belongs on [codereview.se], not here. See [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/155649) for a discussion of which questions go on which site (and changes that may need to be made in the translation).

Comment: If you do move your post there, please read the rules in the help section, since they are a little different from here  - at the very least, ensure enough context is provided and the title describes what the code does instead of your request (i.e. to make the code shorter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first part

```
df['North']=0
df['South']=0
df['Central']=0
df['West']=0
df['East']=0
df['Remote']=0
df['apartment']=0
df['house']=0
df['townhouse']=0
df['unit']=0
df['villa']=0
df['acreage']=0
df['other']=0
```

becomes

```
fields = ['North', 'South', 'Central', 'West', 'East', 'Remote', 'apartment', 'house', 'townhouse', 'unit', 'villa', 'acreage', 'other']
for field in fields:
    df[ field ] = 0
```

this part

```
for i in range(len(df['Region'])):
        if df['Region'][i]=='North':
            df['North'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='South':
            df['South'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='East':
            df['East'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='West':
            df['West'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='Central':
            df['Central'][i]=1
        elif df['Region'][i]=='Remote':
            df['Remote'][i]=1
```

could be replaced with

```
for i in range(len(df['Region'])):
        df[ df['Region'][i] ][i] = 1
```

the other for loop

```
for i in range(len(df['Type_Property'])):
        if df['Type_Property'][i]=='house':
            df['house'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='apartment' or df['Type_Property'][i]=='flat':
            df['apartment'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='townhouse':
            df['townhouse'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='villa':
            df['villa'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='acreage+semi+rural' or df['Type_Property'][i]=='terrance':
            df['acreage'][i]=1
        elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='unit':
            df['unit'][i]=1
        else:
            df['other']=1
```

could be

```
for i in range(len(df['Type_Property'])):
    if df['Type_Property'][i] in ['house', 'apartment', 'townhouse', 'villa', 'unit']:
        df[ df['Type_Property'][i] ][i] = 1
    elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='flat':
        df['apartment'][i]=1
    elif df['Type_Property'][i]=='acreage+semi+rural' or df['Type_Property'][i]=='terrance':
        df['acreage'][i]=1
    else:
        df['other']=1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for contributing! That said, do note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions* in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), documenting that questions which do not meet the topic guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (which includes a requirement that questions be about a *specific problem*) are best repaired, migrated (in this case to our sister site [codereview.se]) or closed rather than answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative leveraging pandas features using `.loc` which will make the operations on a per row basis much faster. I also used lists to group together the regions and property_types.

```
def dummy():

    df = read_csv('path_to_file.csv', header=0)

    regions = ['North', 'South', 'Central', 'West', 'East']
    property_types = ['apartment', 'house', 'townhouse', 'unit', 'villa', 'acreage', 'other']
    columns_to_update = regions + property_types

    for column in columns_to_update
      df[region] = 0

    for region in regions:
        df.loc[df.Region.str == region, region] = 1

    for property_type in property_types:
        if property_type == 'apartment':
            possible_types = [property_types, 'flat']
        elif property_type == 'acreage':
            possible_types = [property_type, 'acreage+semi+rural', 'terrance']
        else: 
            possible_types = [property_types]

        df.loc[df.Type_Property.str.isin(possible_types), property_type] = 1
```

Additionally, I want to share a link with that could help you in your process of optimizing pandas: [A Beginner’s Guide to Optimizing Pandas Code for Speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Comment: thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up, not sure how to make it more efficient

```
import pandas as pd

def dummy():
    df=pd.read_csv('DF.csv',header=0)
    region_list = ['North', 'South', 'Central', 'West', 'East']

    for region in region_list:
      df[region] = 0

    for i in range(len(df['Region'])):
      for region in region_list:
        if df['Region'][i]== region:
            df[region][i]=1

    housing_list = ['apartment', 'house', 'townhouse', 'unit', 'villa', 'acreage', 'other']

    for item in housing_list:
      df[item] = 0


    for i in range(len(df['Type_Property'])):
      for item in housing_list:
        if df['Type_Property'][i]== item:
            df[item][i]=1

    df.to_csv('Dummied.csv')

dummy()
```